# Why does Ping interval effect the RTT value?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, latency

In ping, "-i" is that wait interval in seconds between sending consecutive packets.

I have 2 servers (Host1, 2) and plug 10G NICs into each server. I try to ping Host2 from Host1.

```
$ sudo ping 10.0.0.2 -c 100
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.191 ms
...
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=100 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 received, 0% packet loss, time 89999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.116/0.169/0.231/0.039 ms
```

The average RTT is 0.169ms

---

Then I try to decrease the interval.

```
$ sudo ping 10.0.0.2 -c 100 -i 0.0001
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
...
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=100 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.045/0.112/0.027 ms, ipg/ewma 0.079/0.060 ms
```

The average RTT is 0.045ms?!

---

Interval = 1s, RTT = 0.169ms

Interval = 0.1ms, RTT = 0.045ms

Why is there a lower RTT with a smaller interval?

Comment: You might be seeing multiple messages being sent in the one ethernet frame.  So the RTT will now be RTT/number of messages per frame because they all get sent in the one message, but ping doesn't realise this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you performed this experiment multiple times and consistently saw lower RTT:

The answer is likely in the src code of ping. It might be setting a very small interval means that response are being processed in a more timely fashion.

The RTT figure is mostly the flight time of the packet but also includes some small part that composed of how quickly the OS can process the response. I believe icmp echo / reply is all handled at kernel level.